# Aligning labels with line connecting feature to its label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2

I have labelled a points layer by defining a line between points and labels, because points were overlapping too much. Using additional columns in the points layer attributes table (`LABEL_X` and `LABEL_Y`), I can move the labels manually.

To achieve that, I have added a 'Geometry Generator' in the Style section of the layer's Properties dialog. To define the geometry generator, I have used the following expression where `$x` and `$y` are the features' coordinates and `LABEL_X` and `LABEL_Y` are the labels' coordinates:

`make_line(make_point($x,$y),make_point("LABEL_X","LABEL_Y"))`.

My issue is that **labels do not align properly with the line connecting them to features**. There seems to be a default offset. How could I correct it? The images below show (1) the way labels display inside the map canvas and (2) the Geometry Generator definition.

---

**Image 1** : Labels with connecting-to-features lines

[image]

**Image 2** : Geometry Generator definition

[image]

Comment: how did you define the placement of the label? does it look better if you choose 'offset from point' set to 0?

Comment: Placement is `Around Point`, but the result is the same with `Offset from Point`. I have tried to change the parameters within this section, without success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of my answer but i think i had something very similar recently.
The labelling of your point layer is "data defined", did you check the **horizontal and vertical alignment** ? both properties have predefined values that should be chosen among *([Left|Center|Right])* or *([Bottom|Base|Half|Cap|Top])*.

It seems to me that your labels are currently left-aligned ... no ?

Comment: That's it! Many thanks... Instead of adding new columns to my points layer's attributes table, I clicked the both drop-down menus for `Horizontal` and `Vertical` alignments and then clicked `Edit...`. I just had to enter `'Center'` for horizontal parameter and `'Half'` for the vertical one (as explained in the Description section inside the drop-down menu). Display is now perfect!

Comment: glad it helps ! ... just a question : do u generate the "LABEL_X" and "LABEL_Y" manually ... or ?

Comment: Yes, I just change the position of certain labels manually in the map canvas and these columns update automatically with the new label coordinates.