# QGIS - create linking lines or arrows to points when I move lables manually

Tags: qgis, labeling

When I move labels manually in QGIS by using the data-defined placements X and Y fields, I wonder if a line or arrow can be inserted automatically which will link the new label position to the point in question?

Comment: U can also use this ressource [aligning labels with line connecting feature to its label in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255349/aligning-labels-with-line-connecting-feature-to-its-label-in-qgis) (asked yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Easy Custom Labeling](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/) plugin leader lines will be added automatically when you move the label.