# Composer, shapes and geometry generator

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I wanted to change the way shapes are rendered **in QGIS composer**.

I tried for example to add an ellipse in the composer and choosed **geometry generator** in the styling options. I let Polygon/Multipolygon in the geometry type.

Once modified with these parameter the ellipse disappear, giving me a "blank" object.

Does QGIS allow this kind of things ?

Comment: Geometry generator symbology tends not to display too well in the composer legend if that is what you mean (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255504/missing-icon-within-legend-if-layer-has-a-complex-styling-with-qgis). Unless you mean adding an ellipse object in composer, styled using the geometry generator? I doubt that'd work as there's no real data for the styling to work with ($geometry, etc)... Have you tried adding a circle shape and then resizing it in one dimension (i.e., squashing it)

Comment: yes i mean adding an ellipse object in the composer (or any kind of other object in fact). is **$geometry** returning nothing in that case ? The output preview at the bottom seems ok though ....

Comment: Hmm. In QGIS 2.18.16 I'm getting a NULL for $geometry. However in QGIS 2.99 there is some kind of data there, geom_to_wkt($geometry) returns coordinates that seem to be valid in my CRS but don't change regardless of whether you move the shape or change the Reference Map. Putting in a custom WKT geometry doesn't seem to work either. I guess geometry generator wasn't exactly designed for this use case...